# Update the Value of the ListView Item In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a Listview that is showing a list .So on the click of the listview i have a customDialog.In that i am taking some values from the user.So want once the user enters the details and click on the ok button ,then i have to update the value of that item from the listview and when all the item of the listview has been updated then compare it with the previous value to check whether all the item are updated or not .Help me on this how could i do this

**Activity Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iween_booking_page);
        intent = getIntent();
        isReturn  = (Boolean) intent.getExtras().get("isReturn");
        searchParam = (HashMap<String,String>) intent.getExtras().get("searchParam");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passengerList);
        emailId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        continuebooking = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.continuebooking);
        firstName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastName);
        mobileNumber =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);


        setTittle();
        if(searchParam.get("NoOfChild").equals("0") && searchParam.get("NoOfInfant").equals("0")&& searchParam.get("NoOfAdult").equals("1")){

        } else {


            passengerList = getPassengerList(passengerInfo);
            showPassengerListView(passengerList);

        }

        continuebooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(searchParam.get("NoOfChild").equals("0") && searchParam.get("NoOfInfant").equals("0") && searchParam.get("NoOfAdult").equals("1")){
                    if(firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
                    }
                    if(lastName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        lastName.setError("Enter LastName");
                    }
                    if(mobileNumber.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        mobileNumber.setError("Enter Mobile No.");
                    }
                }else{
                     int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
                     listData = new String[count];
                     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();

                     }
                     for(int i=0;i<listView.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                         for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
                             if(listData[j]==listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString()){
                                 Log.d("listData data", listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString());
//                              View v=listView.getChildAt(i);
//                              TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
//                              tv.setError("Please change the data");
                              }
                        }
                     }
                    } 


            }
        });



    }



    private void showPassengerListView(final String[] passengerList) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, passengerList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
//              int itemPosition     = position;
//              String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                View v=listView.getChildAt(position);
                TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setError(null);
                passengerInformationPopup(passengerList,position);
            }
        });
    }






    public void passengerInformationPopup(final String[] passengerList, final int position) {
        final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(Test.this,R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.passenger_details_dialog); 


        final EditText firstNameDialog;
        final EditText lastNameDialog;
        ImageView continueBooking;
        dateofBirth = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dateofBirth);
        firstNameDialog = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastNameDialog =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.LastName);
        continueBooking =(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.continuebooking);
        if((passengerList[position].contains("Child"))|| (passengerList[position].contains("Infant"))){
            dateofBirth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }else{
                dateofBirth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        dateofBirth.setClickable(true);
        dialog.show();

        continueBooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                isSuccess= true;
                if(firstNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    firstNameDialog.setError("Enter FirstName");
                    isSuccess= false;
                }
                if(lastNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    lastNameDialog.setError("Enter LastName");
                    isSuccess= false;
                }
                if((passengerList[position].contains("Child"))|| (passengerList[position].contains("Infant"))){
                    if(dateofBirth.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        dateofBirth.setError("Date of Birth Can't be blank");
                        isSuccess= false;
                    }
                 }
                if(isSuccess){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    View v=listView.getChildAt(position);
                    TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setText(firstNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString()+" "+lastNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString());


                }
            }
        });

    }
```

passengerInformationPopup function i have to update the items values of the ListView .In on create continueBooking i have to check whether all the items are updated or not

[Before Updation](http://s18.postimg.org/fkkzluomx/First_Look.png)
[After Updation](http://s23.postimg.org/73ie62ryj/Second_Look.png)

Comment: what views does your listview row items have?

Comment: @Raghunandan it will be like Adult1,Adult2,Child1.So of the user clicks on Adult1 it will take his name and then in the listview i have to update the Adult1 to the name that the user has provided use.Same case for each item.Once he clik on done button then i have to check whether all listview items are updated or not

Comment: not clear could you post a snap shot of your listview

Comment: have a string as a class member. assign the value entered by the user in pop function to the string.   on list item click `View parent = (View)view.getParent();
                    TextView tv =(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
                    passengerInformationPopup(passengerList,position);
                    tv.setText(value)`. still its unclear not enough details. provide more info

Comment: added the images Please see i am stucked in this from last 2 days pls help to resolve this

Comment: what happens wen you try the above? did you give it a try ?

Comment: it is updating the text but when i am try to get the values from this code int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
      listData = new String[count];
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                      listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
                     
               } to compare it with previous one the it is giving me same privous values

Comment: @Raghunandan i have updated the complete code pls help me on this hope it will give the perfect picture what i want to do

Comment: @Raghunandan have u got something for me what i have to do

Comment: i gave you the code in the comment. i don't think i can help further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update the Value of Item in the ListView Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312539/update-the-value-of-item-in-the-listview-android)

Answer (score 5):

Never update `ListView` items directly. Update data in your storage and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Comment: Thanks very much kriomant - this problem has been annoying me for ages.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an `ArrayAdapter` with the data for your list. Then when you manipulate the data in that array you can call `.notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adabter to refresh your view.
Be aware that it have to be the same arraylist! so you cant call `arraylist = new ArrayList();` that will destroy the reference. Instead use `arraylist.clear();` and then `arraylist.addAll(data);`

Here is an example:

```
    public class GroupsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     *            Context
     * @param objects
     *            Array of objects to show in the list.
     */
    public GroupsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Object = getItem(position);

        /* Initialize strings */
        String nameText = group.getName();
        boolean upToDate = group.isUpToDate();

        /* Get the layout for the list rows */
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }
            rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                         //do stuff here
                    }
            });


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how could i identify which array position i have update in the array.so that the position of the items won't change see my code what i have done

Comment: Create you own class that extends ArrayAdapter then you create the onClicklistener in the getView method, that method is called with the int position parm

Comment: will u post some sample code for my problem how to update and validate the listview item

Comment: This code is insted of all the code in your onCreate method. Create an adabter and set it on the listview.

Comment: what is happening now it is updating the value of the item but i when i am trying to get the value of the item then i am getting the previous value

Comment: Try getting and setting the value in the same arraylist (The one you called the adapter with)